# How to plot the Zeeman splitting of a nucleus in a magnetic field

Tags: quantum-spin

I have a system that is described by the Hamiltonian
$
H=A_Q(3I_z^2-I^2+\eta\frac{I_+^2-I_-^2}{2})-\gamma\hbar I.B_{ext}
$
where $I$ is the spin operator of a nucleus, $B_{ext}$ is the external field and all other parameters are known constants. This is the quadrupolar interaction and magnetic field as found in a quantum dot. I want to plot how the Zeeman energy changes as a function of magnetic field. How do I use this system to calculate this?

Comment: Is $\eta$ real or imaginary? Because $I^2_+ - I^2_-$ is anti-hermitian. Once that is sorted out, you can try perturbation theory. I imagine you only care about the spin space of the nucleus and nothing else, right? You mean $-\gamma \hbar I \cdot B_{\mathrm{ext}}$ for the last term, right?

Comment: On the other hand, if you can work with a specific spin in mind then the matrix problem should be tractable.

Comment: $A_Q$, $\eta$ and $\gamma$ are all real constants. Yes that's what I mean for the last term and doing this for a particular spin is fine. Eventually I want to do it for Indium which has spin 9/2.

Comment: Ok, but my only issue with this Hamiltonian is that all the terms are hermitian, as they should, except for $I^2_+ - I^2_-$. The eigenvalues of $I^2_+ - I^2_-$ are either 0 or imaginary which is not good. Maybe you mean $I^2_+ + I^2_-$?.

Comment: I'm defining $I_\pm=I_x\pm iI_y$ if that helps? The minus sign is definitely in the equation. It's the quadrupolar interaction.

Comment: Well we have $I^2_{\pm} = I^2_x-I^2_y \pm i \left( I_x I_y + I_y I_x \right)$, hence $\frac{1}{2} \left(I^2_{+} + I^2_{-} \right) = I^2_x-I^2_y$, which is what I think you want there.

Comment: The definition I have comes from Eq. 5 in this paper: https://journals.aps.org/prb/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevB.85.115313.
I'm trying to reproduce Figure  4 if this is helpful.

Comment: Yes, I'd bet a hundred dollars that's a typo. It should be $I^2_{+}+I^2_{-}$ instead. Since you have a specific spin, you can write the matrix representation of the Hamiltonian explicitly. Use the matrices at the end of this section: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics)#Higher_spins) for the spin you desire, plug the parameters that they give you, find the eigenvalues and plot them with respect to $B$. Use Mathematica or something similar.

Comment: @secavara Could you please summarize this productive comment discussion as a proper answer?